# Why Does My Client Say They Need This Long Paragraph Under Their Web Forms?

Tags: terms-of-service, disclaimers

Apparently their compliance department (they're a for profit college) says they have to have this under every form, but I've never seen anything like this:

> Clicking the contact us today button constitutes your express written
>   consent, without obligation to purchase, to be contacted (including
>   through automated means, e.g. dialing & text messages) via telephone,
>   mobile device (including SMS & MMS), and/or email, even if your
>   telephone number is on a corporate, state or the National Do Not Call
>   Registry, and you agree to our terms of use and privacy policy.

Do you think they are wrong, and if not, what would be the reason? Is that law?

Comment: @ColleenV This. And CAN-SPAM.